# how does a JAR component differ from an EAR? (application server)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, glassfish, ejb, ear

What's the [distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_(file_format)) between a `JAR` and an `EAR` file relative to `EJB`'s?  Glassfish help says:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ GlassFish_Server/bin/asadmin deploy --help
```

...

```
       --type
           The packaging archive type of the component that is being deployed.
           Possible values are as follows:

           car
               The component is packaged as a CAR file.

           ear
               The component is packaged as an EAR file.

           ejb
               The component is an EJB packaged as a JAR file.

           osgi
               The component is packaged as an OSGi bundle.

           rar
               The component is packaged as a RAR file.

           war
               The component is packaged as a WAR file.
```

So an `EJB` can be packaged as a `JAR` file?  What is the functional difference?  Specifically, what can an `EAR` component do which a `JAR` **cannot**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EAR -** Ear files are basically intended to contain complete enterprise applications.  it contains all of the components that make up a particular Java EE application. The enterprise application is defined as a collection of .jar files, resources, classes, and multiple Web applications

**JAR -** Java Archives (JAR) A JAR file encapsulates one or more Java classes, a manifest, and a descriptor. Jar files are basically intended to hold generic libraries of Java classes, resources etc. Also, the JAR files are the lowest level of archive. JAR files are used in Java EE for packaging EJBs and client-side Java Applications.

Comment: Is an `EJB` module, as defined by Netbeans, packaged as an `EAR`?  Or, as you suggest in your answer, as a `JAR`?  If you'd expand on that point it would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to archive it as Enterprise application, you can create it as EAR, or if you want to archive it as Java application which contains EJB modules, EJB client modules and utility modules, you can create it as JAR..hope this helps :)